# What impact will adverse immigration history have on UK visa application?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration

This was more of a misunderstanding. This happened in India a few yesrs ago. I was told my visa extension was approved by the ministry. However, upon exit registration (required 24hrs before departure) the officer made a note on my passport that this "extension" was "an order to regularize my overstay." The note further said I was "directed to leave india"  by the next day. This "overstay" was 10 days over my 30 day stay per visit on the multiple entry visa.  The Indian bureaucracy is very different from other countries.

I have since traveled to India on the same and new visas 50+ times without any problems. The UK visa application form requires me to declare if I have ever been required to leave a country. How should I explain this situation and what impact will it have on my application? I have travelled to the UK more than 30 times without any issues. I'm also a frequent traveler to other countries and don't tend to have issues.

I also plan to travel to Australia. They ask if I have ever overstayed a visa. Does this mean I'll not be able to travel there?

Comment: For someone as well traveled as you are, it should be pretty obvious overstaying anywhere is never a positive. Nobody knows if Australia will approve your visa application.

Comment: @Paul of Osawatomie what would be the best way to explain the situation?  In reality, I was told I was authorized to stay until I was ready to leave.

Comment: I know for certain India and Australia do not share data. Personally I wouldn't tell Australia I overstayed in India, no way. No way they will find out if you renewed your passport. Checking your postings, it seems you tend to have a lot of problems with immigration all over the place. That's concerning, you should respect immigration laws.

Comment: @Paul of Osawatomie some countries ask for your old passports when you apply for a visa. I think I'll avoid travel to Australia for now. On the other hand I am a frequent traveler to the UK. As for respecting immigration laws, I have to make about 10 international trips a year. With the state of travel these days some problems are inevitable. Immigration officers around the world tend to go through my passports but not once have they questioned me about this particular incident. Perhaps it's not really a big concern.

Comment: Gradually because of information technology and databases and terror, immigration systems are becoming more connected and it is in our interest to walk the fine line although I agree they can be tedious and easily broken without malicious intent. I also travel internationally about 7 times a year. `I think I'll avoid travel to Australia for now.` - if it's too risky, sure. Because a bad result there will probably be transmitted to the Five Eyes including UK and you don't want o jeopardize your freedom to enter UK

Comment: @Paul of Osawatomie coming to the UK, they need me to declare this "direction to leave." I had to stay for longer related to a death in the family. I believed I had undertaken all necessary paperwork. But then again, this was India. I had a previous visa extension in India where they told me I would have to pay each officer involved for their "services." how would something like this compare to a visa refusal? Plenty of people get a visa after having being previously refused.

Answer (score 2):

It means that they will *consider* this fact as one factor among many. We don't know the details, we don't know what Australia has in their databases about you or what they can access from their partners.

- Your "misunderstanding" reduces your credibility.
- It helps that you got subsequent visa from the same country.

Needless to say, any attempt to lie about this will damage your credibility even more.